# Ошибка при добавлении VideoView

Tags: android, android-studio, videoview

Добавляю программным способом VideoView таким образом

```
VideoView vv = new VideoView(this.context);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(7)));
((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llPage)).addView(vv, 1);
```

где `cursor.getString(7)` равно [этому](https://vid.edimdoma.ru/data/video/0007/0938/70938-original.mp4?1421504506). В итоге получаю ошибку

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: apk.fridge.ru.fridge, PID: 10272
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:515)
at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:354)
at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:71)
at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:607)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score -1):

По всей видимости, Вы передаете при создании VideoView контекст, равный null. Попробуйте иначе:

```
new VideoView(Activity.this);
```

Comment: не помогает, но контекст не null